# Why do they choose numbers like 16, 32, 128 in programming?

Tags: math, data-structures, types, storage

Sometimes in code, I see the developer chooses a number like 32 for a package of data. Or in a game, the loaded terrain of a map has the size of 128*128 points.
I know it has something to do with the maximum size of datatypes. Like a Char has 8 bits, etc.
But why don't they just use numbers like 100*100 for a map, a list, or a Minecraft chunk?

If I have 8 bits to store a (positive) number, I can count to 2^8 = 256.
When I choose the size of a map chunk, I could choose a width of 250 in stead of 256. But it seems that is not a good idea. Why?

Comment: Because powers of two are important when everything is based on binary `0`s and `1`s. A cross-site duplicate, astonishingly enough: http://superuser.com/questions/358031/why-does-everything-in-computing-work-with-a-base-number-of-2-to-the-power-of-x

Comment: 128*128 is 16kb exactly. Aligns nicely at page boundaries, which may often be important.

Comment: Because computers only have two fingers, called 0 and 1. 10, 100, 1000 only seem round to you because you have ten fingers.

Comment: Just imagine how wonderful our world could be: 64 minutes per hour, 1024 meters per km, 4 fingers per hand...

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes developers *do* use numbers like 250 or 100. It's not at all uncommon. (1920 appears in a lot of screen resolutions for example.)

But numbers like 8, 32, and 256 are special because they're powers of 2. For datatypes, like 8-bit integers, the number of possible elements of this type is a power of 2, namely, 2^8 = 256. The sizes of various memory boundaries, disk pages, etc. work nicely with these numbers because they're also powers of two. For example, a 16,384-byte page can hold 2048 8-byte numbers, or 256 64-byte structures, etc. It's easy for a developer to count how many items of a certain size fit in a container of another size if both sizes are powers of two, because they've got many of the numbers memorized.

Comment: They're called [Preferred numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_number#Computer_engineering)

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer emphasizes that data with these sizes fits well into memory blocks, which is of course true. However it does not really explain why the memory blocks themselves have these sizes:

Memory has to be addressed. This means that the location of a given datum has to be calculated and stored somewhere in memory, often in a CPU register. To save space and calculation cost, these addresses should be as small as possible while still allowing as much memory as possible to be addressed. On a binary computer this leads to powers of 2 as optimal memory or memory block sizes.

There is another related reason: Calculations like multiplication and division by powers of 2 can be implemented by shifting and masking bits. This is much more performant than doing general multiplications or divisions.

An example: Say you have a 16 x 16 array of bytes stored in a contiguous block of memory starting at address 0. To calculate the row and column indices from the address, generally you need to calculate `row=address / num_columns` and `column=address % num_columns` (% stands for remainder of integer division).

In this special case it is much easier for a binary computer, e.g.:

```
address:           01011101
mask last 4 bits:  00001101 => column index
shift right by 4:  00000101 => row index
```

Comment: "To save space and calculation cost, these addresses should be as small as possible while still allowing as much memory as possible to be addressed." Great comment, +1